# AlertDialog has not come out because cannot getText of a button

Tags: android, button, gettext, android-alertdialog

My Alert dialog message doesn't come out because I cannot get the text of the button. After that the program will directly go to my `EventActivity`. How can settle this problem?

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v.getId() == insertButton.getId()) {

            if(colorButton.getText().toString().equals("Color")){
                colorAlert.show();
            }
        }
}
```

This is variable

```
AlertDialog colorAlert;
```

AlertDialog in the `OnCreate()`

```
AlertDialog.Builder CA = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        CA.setTitle("Alert Message!");
        CA.setMessage("Please insert the level of important for the event.");
        CA.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                colorAlert.dismiss();
                startActivity(new Intent(this, EventActivity.class));
            }
        });
        colorAlert = CA.create();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok look like you need more help, here is one solution... i let you deal with the EventActivity ;)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final Context context=this;
    public static String EXTRA_MESSAGE;
    Button colorButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_test);

        colorButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        colorButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if(colorButton.getText().toString().equals("Color")){


                    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    alertBuilder.setMessage("myDialog").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EventActivity.class);
                            String message = colorButton.getText().toString();
                            intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            }
                    }).setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                            }
                    });

                    AlertDialog myAlert = alertBuilder.create();
                    myAlert.show();

                }   

            }
        });


    }
```

Answer (score 3):

When you compare a String in Java, use `YOUR_STRING.equals("Color");`

Update:
change your `while` into `if` , because your are running it once.

The move your

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, EventActivity.class));
```

in your alertbox positive button handler.

[Comparing Strings in Java.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: that's mean I need to have my code is `colorButton.getText().toString().equals("Color")`? If like this then it is stuck at there.

Comment: @user2274349 updated. Change while into if. You should post code for your alertbox if you still need help on the next step.

Comment: Again... `startActivity(new Intent(this, EventActivity.class));` error if I put in my alertbox there.

Comment: done edit...the error is in the `startActivity(new Intent(this, EventActivity.class));`

Comment: `colorButton.getText().toString().equals( "Color");` change `==` to `.equals("Color");` If you still get an error post Error/logcat/stacktrace.

Comment: it is exactly cannot run. Because the error still at there. `startActivity(new Intent(this, EventActivity.class));` this error cannot fix then the alert shown "Please fix the error before run."

Comment: use `YourCurrentClassName.this.startActivity(new Intent(this, EventActivity.class));`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to wtsang02 answer, you shouldn't put your alert.show in a while like this one... I see coming the infinite loop ;)